# Ajax request in for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'd like to loop 100 times ajax request with for loop. This is my code :

```
for(var i=1; i<100; i++)
{
  var num = i+1;

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "http://localhost/test/1/2/main.php?t="+num+"", true);
  request.send(null);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (request.readyState == 4) {

        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(request.responseText, "text/html");

        var rows = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

        var sum = 0;
        for(var j=0; j<rows.length;j++)
        {
            sum += parseInt( rows[j].getElementsByTagName("td")[7].textContent.trim() );
        }
        alert(num);
    }


  }
```

}

But it's not working. 
In console I see 100 times this information:

> XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/test/1/2/main.php?t=2".
>   XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/test/1/2/main.php?t=3".

Etc. So everything should be ok. 
But I see alert only 14 times (I don't now why 14),no 100.

Why this program not working?

Comment: Could you try using the for loop inside the onreadystatechange function, cuz, you are actually calling it so many times. Do you want to do it, or its just your code inside that function which needs to be loaded 100 times?

Comment: When I delete 
` if (request.readyState == 4)`
I get alert 11times (?) and the console shows this error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined`
in line `var rows = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");`

Comment: Just a recommendation: Ajax calls can be made simpler and crossbrowser-compatibility is guaranteed when using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and its [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please below code. Which will allow to fire ajax call only after previous has been completed. So no ajax call will missed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var num = 0;
    doAjax(0);
    function doAjax(arrCount) 
    {
        if(num<100){
            num += 1;
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", "http://localhost/test/1/2/main.php?t="+num+"", true);
            request.send(null);
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                    var parser = new DOMParser();
                    var doc = parser.parseFromString(request.responseText, "text/html");
                    var rows = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
                    var sum = 0;
                    for(var j=0; j<rows.length;j++)
                    {
                        sum += parseInt( rows[j].getElementsByTagName("td")[7].textContent.trim() );
                    }
                    alert(num);
                    doAjax(num)
                }
            }
        }       
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank You !

Comment: this will be slower than allowing multiple XHR requests at once of course

Comment: Yeah you are right but. It will not miss any Ajax request in this case..

Answer (score 0):

an alternative method using IIFE for closure, and some more advanced DOM and Array methods to make things a little tidier (in my opinion)

```
for(var i=1; i<100; i++) {
    (function(num) { // [1]
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "http://localhost/test/1/2/main.php?t="+num+"", true);
        request.addEventListener('load', function() {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var doc = parser.parseFromString(request.responseText, "text/html");
            var sum = [].map.call( // [2]
                doc.querySelector("table").querySelectorAll("tbody>tr>td:nth-child(8)"), //[3]
                function(cell) { // [4]
                    return parseFloat(cell.textContent.trim());
                }).reduce(function(a, b) { // [5]
                    return a + b;
                });
            alert(num);
        });
        request.send(null);
    }(i + 1));
}
```

explanation:

[1]

```
function(num) {
...
}(i + 1));
```

This is an IIFE, which creates a closure for the value of i + 1 (as num)

[2]

```
[].map.call(x, fn)
```

this creates an array from "x" and calls the map function with the callback fn - we need to do this, because the result of the next part is not an array, but a NodeList.

in the code x is

[3]

```
doc.querySelector("table").querySelectorAll("tbody>tr>td:nth-child(8)")
```

this gets the first table, then the 8th TD from each tr in each tbody

if the returned html is only one table, you can change the above to

```
doc.querySelectorAll("table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(8)")
```

[4] now, fn in the map callback is

```
function(cell) {
    return parseFloat(cell.textContent.trim());
}
```

This gets each cell, and returns the contents parsed to a float

[5] now we have an array of floats - the easiest way to get the sum of an array of numbers is with Array#reduce

```
.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
```

so, now sum has, in one complex statement got the sum of the cells

I use `request.addEventListener('load', fn)` ... same as `request.onload = fn` - it's a personal quirk of mine to mess with OLD internet explorer users :p

`load` is fired once the data is finished loading ... so no more readyState gymnastics needed